# unable to trigger custom material design models to a wordpress menu using a div id

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, material-design

I am unable to trigger custom material design models to a WordPress menu using a `div id`. I want to call the `login model` to the custom login menu of WordPress and register model to the register link. Source code of the models is also given below please check and help me with this issue.
Thanks

This is the [link](https://chunkybrains.com/project/watchawear/test/) of models i want to call.

This is the [link](https://chunkybrains.com/project/watchawear/) where i want to call

```html
<?php /* Template Name: mdb-register */ ?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>WatchAwear Login/Registration Form</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.7.4/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.7.4/js/mdb.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .nav.nav-tabs.md-tabs.tabs-2.light-blue.darken-3 {
            padding: 10px;
            background: #3b3b3b !important;
        }
        .nav-link {
            color: #fff !important;
            border:none !important;
        }
        .nav-link.active {
            color: #020202 !important;
        }
        .nav-link.active:hover {
            background: #fff !important;
            border-color: #fff !important;
        }
        .nav-link:hover {
            background: #0006 !important;
            border-color: #232323 !important;
        }
        .btn.btn-info {
            background-color: #020202 !important;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .btn-outline-info{
            border-color: #020202 !important;
            background-color: transparent !important;
            color: #020202 !important;
        }
        .btn-outline-info:hover {
            border-color: #020202 !important;
            background-color: transparent !important;
            color: #020202 !important;
        }
        #modalLRForm {
            padding-left: 0 !important;
            background: #fff6;
        }
        #modalLRForm1 {
            padding-left: 0 !important;
            background: #fff6;
        }

        /*=========Mobile Styles STARTS============== */
        /* Note: Add new css to the media query below that you want to only effect the Mobile and Tablet Portrait view */

        @media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
            .modal-dialog.cascading-modal .modal-body, .modal-dialog.cascading-modal .modal-footer {
                padding-left: 1rem !important;
                padding-right: 1rem !important;
                color: #616161;
                font-size: 13px !important;
            }
        }
        /*=========Mobile Styles ENDS============== */
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background:#020202;">
<!--Modal: Login / Register Form-->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalLRForm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog cascading-modal" role="document">
        <!--Content-->
        <div class="modal-content">

            <!--Modal cascading tabs-->
            <div class="modal-c-tabs">

                <!-- Nav tabs -->
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs md-tabs tabs-2 light-blue darken-3" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#panel8" role="tab"><i class="fas fa-user-plus mr-1"></i>
                            Register</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="md-form form-sm mb-5">
                        <i class="fas fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
                        <input type="text" id="modalLRInput9" class="form-control form-control-sm validate data-val-required" placeholder="First Name">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="modalLRInput12"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form form-sm mb-5">
                        <i class="fas fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
                        <input type="text" id="modalLRInput10" class="form-control form-control-sm validate data-val-required" placeholder="Last Name">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="modalLRInput12"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form form-sm mb-5">
                        <i class="fas fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
                        <input type="text" id="modalLRInput11" class="form-control form-control-sm validate data-val-required" placeholder="Username">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="modalLRInput12"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-form form-sm mb-5">
                        <i class="fas fa-envelope prefix"></i>
                        <input type="email" id="modalLRInput12" class="form-control form-control-sm validate data-val-required" placeholder="Email">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="modalLRInput12"></label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="md-form form-sm mb-5">
                        <i class="fas fa-lock prefix"></i>
                        <input type="password" id="modalLRInput13" class="form-control form-control-sm validate data-val-required" placeholder="Password">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="modalLRInput13"></label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="md-form form-sm mb-4">
                        <i class="fas fa-lock prefix"></i>
                        <input type="password" id="modalLRInput14" class="form-control form-control-sm validate data-val-required" placeholder="Verify password">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="modalLRInput14" ></label>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Material unchecked -->
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="materialUnchecked">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="materialUnchecked">Terms and Conditions</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center form-sm mt-2">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Sign up <i class="fas fa-sign-in ml-1"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--Footer-->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="options text-left">
                        <p class="pt-1">Already have an account? <a href="#" class="blue-text">Log In</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info waves-effect ml-auto" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Tab panels -->
        </div>
        <!--/.Content-->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="text-center">
    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary my-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalLRForm">Register</a>
</div>


<!--Modal: Login / Register Form-->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalLRForm1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog cascading-modal" role="document">
        <!--Content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!--Modal cascading tabs-->
            <div class="modal-c-tabs">
                <!-- Nav tabs -->
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs md-tabs tabs-2 light-blue darken-3" role="tablist"  >
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#panel7" role="tab"><i class="fas fa-user mr-1"></i>
                            Login</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- Form Start -->
                <div class="modal-body mb-1">
                    <div class="md-form mb-5">
                        <i class="fas fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
                        <input type="text" id="form3" class="form-control form-control-sm validate" placeholder="Username">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="form3"></label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="md-form form-sm mb-4">
                        <i class="fas fa-lock prefix"></i>
                        <input type="password" id="modalLRInput15" class="form-control form-control-sm validate" placeholder="Password">
                        <label data-error="wrong" data-success="right" for="modalLRInput11"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center mt-2">
                        <button class="btn btn-info">Log in <i class="fas fa-sign-in ml-1"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--Footer-->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="options text-center text-md-right mt-1">
                        <p><a href="#" class="blue-text">Forgot Password?</a></p>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-info waves-effect ml-auto" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/.Content-->
    </div>
</div>
<!--Modal: Login / Register Form-->

<div class="text-center">
    <a href="" class="btn btn-danger my-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalLRForm1">LogIn</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. Following the advices of the community, it is recommended to include source code formatted to better understand your issue and find the proper solution. 
Please check the documentation [on how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Added the source code to the post sir please help me.